# refresh mail.app inbox when returning from standby (IMAP)

Tags: mail.app, email, imap, hibernate

When returning from standby mail.app does not refresh my inbox. New mails (or changes to old mails, like move or delete) are not synchronized. I have to manually close mail.app and restart it to make the changes appear.

Is this working as intended or are there settings to change this?

Comment: So the clicking the Send/Receive button doesn't work?

Comment: Well thanks, that's a workaround. Thought it only applied to POP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail.app doesn't automatically check for mail every time focus is put on it's window or every time the computer wakes up. There are several ways for you to configure how, and how often Mail.app synchronizes with servers:

1. You can click the Send/Receive mail button

   - [image: send and receive]
2. You can use the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> keyboard shortcut
3. You can configure your Mail.app to check for mail every minute by clicking the `Mail` menu and then selecting `Preferences`. Under `General` change the `Check for new Messages` configuration.

   - [image]

This way you never have to wait more then 1 minute for mail to be synced. Keep in mind, if you are on battery, this will impact battery life negatively.